# Clicking on a position in a flash object from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, google-chrome-extension

So I've read through a good amount of threads pertaining to this but they either don't fit what I need or I can't. Take for example a question about emulating mouse click... oh just `document.getElementById("blah").click()`... Yeah I've tried that and sadly it won't work... I've tried clicking a position with something like this.

```
function click(target) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 667, 521, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    var cancelled = !target.dispatchEvent(evt);
    if (cancelled) {
        console.log('cancelled');
    } else {
        console.log('not cancelled');
    }
}
```

Which doesn't work. I can't modify the flash object as I'd like to stay within the extension(otherwise I'd just modify the swf). I just want to click within the flash to advance the dialogue. Is this possible? Maybe a helpful chrome API or something?

You might have read my past thread on this topic: [Triggering an element with pointer-events: none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450085/triggering-an-element-with-pointer-events-none)

Comment: Inner contents of a Flash object is outside of DOM so DOM events won't affect it. There's no browser API either. You'll have to write a native OS utility and control it via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: @wOxxOm Okay... I see. You wouldn't happen to know how to have a div be transparent(allow the thing behind it(flash embed) to be clicked on, I'm currently using "pointer-events: none") and still clickable(registers click event handlers), would you?